# Agda: rewrite subexpression

Tags: agda

I'm trying to prove:

```
AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse :
  ∀ {n : ℕ} (todos : Vec Todo (1 + n)) (text : String) →
    Todo.completed (last (AddTodo todos text)) ≡ false
AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse todos text = ?
```

where

```
AddTodoLastAddedElementIsTodo :
  ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {n} (todos : Vec Todo n) (text : String) →
    last (AddTodo todos text) ≡ 
      record
        { id        = 1
        ; completed = false
        ; text      = text
        }
AddTodoLastAddedElementIsTodo todos text = vecLast todos
```

and

```
vecLast : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {l n} (xs : Vec A n) → last (xs ∷ʳ l) ≡ l
vecLast []       = refl
vecLast (_ ∷ xs) = P.trans (prop (xs ∷ʳ _)) (vecLast xs)
  where
    prop : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {n x} (xs : Vec A (suc n)) → last (x ∷ xs) ≡ last xs
    prop xs with initLast xs
    ...        | _ , _ , refl = refl
```

I tried using `rewrite` and got:

```
AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse :
  ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {n} (todos : Vec Todo n) (text : String) →
    Todo.completed (last (AddTodo todos text)) ≡ false
AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse todos text rewrite AddTodoLastAddedElementIsTodo todos text = refl
```

but the error:

```
_a_100 : Agda.Primitive.Level
```

showed up.

I'm not sure how to resolve this.
from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198089/meaning-of-agda-level-error-message-agda-primitive-level) I understand that this is related to the implicit argument. But not sure how to fix it

> This sort of error indicates an unsolved metavariable, which means that Agda has failed to infer an implicit argument

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use `A` for anything in the type of `AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse`. Also, that is not an error, but an unsolved meta.

So what happens is that wherever you use `AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse`, nothing in the arguments or the result type constrains the choice of `A` (and, subsequently, `a`) so the unifier has no way of solving these metavariables. You can make explicit what happens by writing `AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse {a = _} {A = _}` and observing that these two metas are unsolved.

You should simply remove the first two parameters (`a` and `A`) from `AddTodoSetsNewCompletedToFalse`'s type.